# Method to align footer?

Tags: html, css

trying to align my images and text to be on one side and one line, what would be the best method to do this? would I need to make a grid? i have tried the align methods but its not getting the results i expected, any tips to where I am going wrong?

here is an imgur of what I am trying to achieve
[http://imgur.com/a/Jdrw3](https://imgur.com/a/Jdrw3)

https://jsfiddle.net/jygbq0e8/

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Referenzen </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">           
   <h1 align="center">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="A.Willi A.G" /></a>
</h1>       
   <div class="menu_div">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="info.html">Info</a>
   <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</div>  
</li>      
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="personalverleih.html">Personalverleih</a>
   <a href="toolrental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
   <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
   <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
</li>
</div>
   <div class="fadein"> 
   <img src="welder1.png">
   <img src="welder1.png">
   <img src="welder1.png"> 
</div>    

<h2><font color="#004b77">Referenzen</font></h2> 
<p>Wir danken unser langjähriger Kundschaft sehr  für die vertrauen an unser Dienstleistungen und hier eine Auswahl der Beteiligte Projekt bis und mit 2016
    <font color="#004b77"><b>Toni-Areal</b></font> -  Zürich,  <font color="#004b77"><b>Nespresso</b></font> - Romont,  <font color="#004b77"><b>Salle de spectacle Arena</b></font> - Genève, <font color="#004b77"><b>Nostromanlage Krenkraftwerk</b></font> - Beznau, <font color="#004b77"><b>Roche</b></font>- Turm ( Bau 1 ) – Basel, <font color="#004b77"><b>SIG Les Cheneviers</b></font> – Aire-la-Ville, <font color="#004b77"><b>IWB Fernheizungsnetz</b></font>– Basel, <font color="#004b77"><b>BASF-Pharma SA Betreibsunterhalt</b></font> – Evionnaz, <font color="#004b77"><b>Novartis Campus</b></font>– Basel, <font color="#004b77"><b>Coop LoBOS Pratteln+Halba</b></font> – Pratteln, <font color="#004b77"><b>Novartis Bau 222 NSLF</b></font> – Stein (AG), <font color="#004b77"><b>Biozentrum</b></font> – Basel, <font color="#004b77"><b>Infrapark Baselland AG Betreibsunterhalt</b></font> – Muttenz, <font color="#004b77"><b>Galliker Transport AG Logistikcenter</b></font> – Dagmersellen, <font color="#004b77"><b>KVA Renergia</b></font> – Luzern, <font color="#004b77"><b>Nestlé Fabrik</b></font> – Konolfingen, <font color="#004b77"><b>Roche Basel Bau 50,67,91</b></font> – Basel, <font color="#004b77"><b>Nant de Drance</b></font> -  Finhaut, <font color="#004b77"><b>Vierfeld</b></font> – Pratteln,<font color="#004b77"><b>Holzwärmeverbund Fernheizungsnetz</b></font> - Menzingen, <font color="#004b77"><b>Novartis Bau 503,506</b></font> - Basel, <font color="#004b77"><b>EMS Chemie AG Betreibsunterhalt</b></font> - Domat/Ems, <font color="#004b77"><b>Emmi Areal</b></font>  - Luzern,<font color="#004b77"><b>SBB Olten</b></font> – Olten, <font color="#004b77"><b>CSCS Swiss National Supercomputing Centre</b></font> – Lugano, <font color="#004b77"><b>Endress+Hauser AG</b></font> – Reinach BL, <font color="#004b77"><b>Lonza AG Betreibsunterhalt</b></font> – Visp,  <font color="#004b77"><b>Tamoil SA</b></font> – Collombey, SIG Fernwärmenetz – Genève, ARA Bern</font> – Bern, <font color="#004b77">Emmi Milch AG</font> -  Dagmersellen, <font color="#004b77"><b>Konapharma AG</b></font> – Pratteln, <font color="#004b77"><b>CHUV - Centre hospitalier universitaire vaudois</b></font> – Lausanne, <font color="#004b77"><b>Rolex</b></font> – Biel, <font color="#004b77"><b>Swatch Group</b></font> – Boncourt,<font color="#004b77"><b>ELSA-MIFROMA</b></font> - Estavayer-le-Lac, <font color="#004b77"><b>General Electric (Switzerland) GmbH</b></font> – Birr, <font color="#004b77"><b>BIOGEN</b></font>- Lutterbach
</p>

<ul class="thumbnails">
   <li><img src="alpiq.png.gif" /></li>
   <li><img src="General_Electric_logo.svg.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="bacher_logo.gif" /></li>
   <li><img src="basf_logo.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="bilfinger_logo.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="bwt_logo.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="caliqua_logo.gif" /></li>
   <li><img src="cofely.png.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="despraz_logo.GIF" /></li>
   <li><img src="halg_logo.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="hitachi.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="iwbfacebook_logo_180_180.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="jc.png.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="josef_meyer_logo.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="kelag_systems_logo.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="klima_ag.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="lauber.png.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="lehman.png.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="lonza.png.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="rosenmund.png.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="sotta.png.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="tetra_pack_logo.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="trinox_ag.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="voith.png.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="zwahlen_mayr_sa_logo.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="Biogen_Logo_Standard_0.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="logo-elsa-mifroma.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="sbb.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="nestle-2.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="Roche_Logo.svg.png" /></li>
</ul>
<footer>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
   <p align="left"><font color="#fff">Copyright © A.Willi A.G</font></p>
   <p algin="left"><font color="#fff">t +41 (0)79 322 14 20</font></p>
   <p algin="left"><font color="#fff">Wasgenring 94, CH-4055 Basel</font></p>
   <p algin="left"><font color="#fff">support@awilli-ag.ch</font></p>
   <img src="phone_icon.gif" algin="left">
   <img src="mail_icon.png" algin="left">
   <img src="dossier_icon.png" algin="left">
   <img src="location_icon.png" algin="left">
   <img src="" algin="left">
   <img src="swiss.png" algin="center" alt="Swiss Staffing"/>
</div>
</footer>
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body { font-family: verdana; background:white ; color: black; }


}

.menu_div{background-color: #333; width:100%;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

    .fadein { position:absolute; height:500px; width:49px; outline: 1px solid blue; }
    .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }

.menu_div { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 2.9em;
  margin-bottom: -0.4em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  z-index:1000;
  background-color: #333


}
.fadein { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3; 
  background: ;
  width: 100%;
  left: -0.5px;
  top: 0em;


  }

.fadein img{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 4060px;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-height: 400%;
}




.tech-slideshow {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tech-slideshow > div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/collage.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
  animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  animation: moveSlideshow 15s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow:hover .mover-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-66.6666%);  
  }
}


form {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;

  /* Just to center the form on the page */
  margin:  auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* To see the limits of the form */
  padding: 10em;
}

div + div {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

label {
  /* To make sure that all label have the same size and are properly align */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  text-align: left;
}

input, textarea {
  /* To make sure that all text field have the same font settings
     By default, textarea are set with a monospace font */
  font: 1em verdana;

  /* To give the same size to all text field */
  width: 200px;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;

  /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
  border: 2px solid ;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  /* To give a little highligh on active elements */
  border-color: black;
}

textarea {
  /* To properly align multiline text field with their label */
  vertical-align: top

  /* To give enough room to type some text */
  height: 23em;

  /* To allow users to resize any textarea vertically
     It works only on Chrome, Firefox and Safari */
  resize: vertical;
}

.button {
  /* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
  padding-left: 400px; /* same size as the label elements */
}

button {
  /* This extra magin represent the same space as the space between
     the labels and their text fields */
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}

.image-upload img
{
    width: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;

}



.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;  
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    text-align: center;
    border: -0.2px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.flex-container > * {
    padding: 150px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 110%;
    flex: 1 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size:14pt;
}

.article {
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:11px
}

header {
background: white;color:black;
font-size: 0.9em;
}





@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav {text-align:left;-webkit-flex: 1 auto;flex:1 auto;-webkit-order:1;order:1;}
    .article {-webkit-flex:5 0px;flex:5 0px;-webkit-order:2;order:2;}
    footer {-webkit-order:3;order:3;}
}



.indexinfo {

padding:70px;
-webkit-flex: 1 100%;
flex: 1 110%;
height: 70px;
border: px solid black;
height: 200px:
text: center;

}

.sidebar-image-gallery { 

height: 700px;
width: 1323px;

}


    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.thumbnails {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnails li {
  float: center;
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnails li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 60px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white
    {background-position: 50% 90%;}
}
```

Comment: Guess you should go for grids. It will reduce your job of alignment as well as handle responsiveness to some extent. Grid based layouts are very good assistants of a developer. Go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this easily by using Flexbox and its `align-items` property. Here's a quick example:

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.info-img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
    <img class="info-img"  src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/iOS7/PNG/25/Maps/location_filled-25.png" title="Marker Filled" width="25">
    <div class="info-text">
      <p>21 Revolution Street</p>
      <p>Paris, France</p>
    </div>
</div>
```